# Failed: element not interactable : Protractor / Selenium Automation (ElementNotVisibleException)

Tags: java, angularjs, typescript, selenium, protractor

**I am trying to automate a page which has various element types. I am able to login and navigate till that page using Protractor,TypeScript,jasmine2 combination**

- When i try to enter a text in a field, it throws

  > Message: Failed: element not interactable.
- Does it mean that the entire ng-controller or ng-scope is disabled for element interaction for automation?

**Please let me know a solution if there is a way to enable the elements in the page on pageLoad ?**

```
    import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';
    import { Locator } from 'protractor/built/locators';
    import { PageObjects } from '../TestPageObjects/OR';
    import { TestData } from '../TestData/TD';

    var po= new PageObjects();
    var data= new TestData();
    describe('Login', function() {
    it('Login to Server', function() {
    browser.get('http://server01/test/testapp.html');
    element(<Locator>by.xpath(po.login_username)).sendKeys(data.username);
    element(<Locator>by.xpath(po.login_password)).sendKeys(data.password);
    element(<Locator>by.xpath(po.login_loginBtn)).click();
    element(<Locator>by.xpath(po.MainMenu_setup)).click();
    element(<Locator>by.xpath(po.SETUP_company)).click();
    element(<Locator>by.xpath(po.COMPANY_companyDetails)).click();              
browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.id('ifmPortalInfrastturcture')).getWebElement());
    browser.sleep(10000);
   browser.element(<Locator>by.xpath(po.CompanyName)).clear();
              browser.element(<Locator>by.xpath(po.CompanyName)).sendKeys('ANN');   
 });
 });
```

I expected the behavior to be like entering the text but the terminal showed element not interact-able.

PageObject (PO) selector is below:

```
export class PageObjects
{
    public login_username: string ='//*[@id="username"]';
    public login_password: string ='//*[@id="password"]';
    public login_loginBtn: string ='//*[@id="btnSubmit"]';
    public MainMenu_setup: string ='//a[span[text()="Setup"]]';
    public SETUP_company:  string ='//a[span[text()="Company"]]';
    public COMPANY_companyDetails:  string ='//a[span[text()="Company Details"]]'
    public CompanyName: string = '//label[contains(.,"Company Name")]/following::input[1]';
    //a[span[text()="Receipts"]]
    //a[span[text()="Control Text"]]
}
```

HTML Page is below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="portalInfrastructure" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>iProof Axon</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
    <style>

@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('iProofCDN/Templates/Default/Styles/LTR/assets/css/Common/icons/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
    src: url('iProofCDN/Templates/Default/Styles/LTR/assets/css/Common/icons/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('iProofCDN/Templates/Default/Styles/LTR/assets/css/Common/icons/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2'), 
         url('iProofCDN/Templates/Default/Styles/LTR/assets/css/Common/icons/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0') format('woff'), 
         url('iProofCDN/Templates/Default/Styles/LTR/assets/css/Common/icons/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype'), 
         url('iProofCDN/Templates/Default/Styles/LTR/assets/css/Common/icons/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
    </style>
</head>

<body ng-controller="PortalInfrastructureController as menuList" class="pace-done " ng-init='setPageUrlByPageType("Authenticate", "#pageManager")' id="bdyPageManager">
    <div id="pageManager"></div>
    <div id="MultiWindowRight" class="noItem " style="display:none">
        <a href="#" class="ToggleRightMenu"><img data-imgsrc="/Templates/Default/Styles/LTR/assets/images/RightArrow.png" /></a>
        <div class="MultiWindow"></div>
    </div>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="iProofCDN/Templates/Default/Scripts/JsBundle/Common/ProofConfig.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
        window.top.ScriptLoader('PageManager', window.document, function () {
            //default
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please provide HTML code and po's selectors?

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Using Protractor](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/e2e-testing#using-protractor).

Comment: Hi @ Yevhen, i have edited the post and added the PO selector code and the HTML code.

Comment: In the page if i do a search in the Elements tab of the ChromeDeveloperTools, 

**//html[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml']** : i get 4 values.

The element is inside the iFrame **ifmPortalInfrastturcture** and this frame is inside the first XML Namespace.

Answer (score 0):

with some research one of my colleague found a solution.

The container elements were hidden for access and we unlocked using the following script:

**JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('Parks').style.display='block';");**

*NOTE: a Div named "Parks" was a child inside the xmlns which is again a child of an iFrame.*